# Date query with the current date between two date_time columns

Tags: date, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have a fusion table with two date_time columns. The fist one is the start date (Startdatum) and in the other column is the end date (Einddatum).

I want to do a query with the current date, and only show the KML-lines on a map where the current date lies between the start and end date.

I tried to use the code below to create a string with a date format:

```
var time_date = new Date();
var day = time_date.getDate(); 
var month = time_date.getMonth()+1;
var year = time_date.getFullYear();
var date = (year+"."+month+"."+day);
```

To show the KML-lines on the map I tried to use the following code:

```
 layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  map: map,
  heatmap: { enabled: false },
  query: {
    select: "col2",
    from: "1mOMP1seJq4FdiNTugsfylZaJc8sKcSlfJKUuTJjv",
    where: "'Startdatum' <= date AND 'Einddatum' >= date"

  },
  options: {
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  }
});
```

Unfortunatly the map shows all the KMS-lines regardless what date is in one of the columns.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. the `where`-clause is wrong, it has to be

   ```
   where: "Startdatum <= '"+date+"' AND Einddatum >= '"+date+"'"
   ```
2. the `date`-format seems to be wrong. Although the used format `yyyy.MM.dd` is defined in the documentation, it doesn't work. The format  `yyyy-MM-dd` currently works for me(but it's not defined in the documentation).

   ```
   var date = (year+"-"+month+"-"+day);
   ```

   (in case that day  and month be less than 10  they wouldn't match the pattern, but that doesn't seem to be an issue)

Beyond that: when you fix these 2 mentioned parts it currently works(for me), but I've tried it a couple of hours ago and got unstable results.