# Write Query to Compare time in google fusion table

Tags: sql, google-fusion-tables

I want to get all the entries from google fusion table which satisfies the condition in a given date
          Time column > specific time

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql=SELECT * FROM 1WjowbI77j1WFcn3IEtbwBymhVZh8jfmP_dg1epd9 WHERE Date = '2015-02-23' AND Time > '10:25:04'&key=AIzaSyCALoSz00ZY3zTL1D_xUTD9GMb3T1ocBdU
```

But it gives me all the entries as result..

fusion table :

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1WjowbI77j1WFcn3IEtbwBymhVZh8jfmP_dg1epd9&key=AIzaSyCALoSz00ZY3zTL1D_xUTD9GMb3T1ocBdU#rows:id=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is assumed that the type of `Time` column is `Date/Time` and format is  `H:mm:ss AM/PM`

In that case, it seems the filtering on `Date/Time` column is **not** supported.

According to [Row and Query SQL Reference](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference#Select) documentation:

> **Filtering on DATETIME**
>
> When filtering on a column of type `DATETIME`, the `<value>` should be
>   formatted as one of the following supported formats:
>
> ```
> MMM dd, yy
> MM/dd/yy
> MM-dd-yy
> MMM-dd-yy
> yyyy.MM.dd
> dd-MMM-yy
> MMM/yy
> MMM yy
> dd/MMM/yy
> yyyy
> ```

Having said that, you could consider to apply filtering to the returned results as demonstrates the following JavaScript example:

```js
var key = 'AIzaSyCALoSz00ZY3zTL1D_xUTD9GMb3T1ocBdU'
var sql = "SELECT * FROM 1WjowbI77j1WFcn3IEtbwBymhVZh8jfmP_dg1epd9 WHERE Date = '2015-02-23'";
var requestUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql=" + sql +  "&key=" + key;
var timeKey = '10:25:04';
$.getJSON(requestUrl, function(data) {
    var filteredRows = data.rows.filter(function(row){
        var dtCur = Date.parse(row[3] + ' ' + row[7]);
        var dtKey = Date.parse(row[3] + ' ' + timeKey);  
        if (dtCur > dtKey) {
            return row;
        }    
    });
    
    //print
    var output = JSON.stringify(filteredRows, null, 2);
    $("#output").text(output);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre style="background-color: #c0c0c0" id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: My prior idea was to reduce the data that I retrieve each time..In this method we retrieve the same data each time and then get what we want..Is there any way that I can use to get less data from the table each time.. ex: 1st request to the table : get all the data 2nd request to the table : all data that are updated after the first retrieval then append to the 1st data and so on

Comment: it sounds feasible, but it requires the introduction of additional column that will store the information whether the column  should be updated next time or not. To summarize:  1st request : get all the data and  2nd request : update table to save information about updated rows 3d request: get only rows that have to be updated...

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you exactly what's going on there, the only issue I see that you've omited the AM(PM)

The documentation mentions the DateTime-Formats supported for filtering, but I think this part of the documentation is outdated(see: [Date query with the current date between two date_time columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070855/date-query-with-the-current-date-between-two-date-time-columns/26079933#26079933) ).

For me it works as expected when I make a copy of the table(you may do the same):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql=SELECT * FROM 12tl0d4jZRkhPD9ZdBzP2QzK4TyEu-U_Dnn8kimft WHERE Date = '2015-02-23' AND Time > '10:25:04 AM'&key=yourKey
```

Maybe they run a validation when a table will be copied and store DateTime-columns internally in another format.